# A question about ERC-20 Token

Tags: erc-20, tokens

New to Crypto somehow. When an ERC-20 token is deployed gas fees are taken. So as the admin, I can transfer, and they take some money from my BNB accounts.
Does this mean, if the holders of my token want to transfer my tokens , say to others for payments etc , does this mean they would have to have some amount of money inside their BNB accounts as well? or they can just run the transfers without problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All transactions require gas to execute. The gas cost is paid with the network's native asset - in BSC it's BNB and in Ethereum it's Ether. So anyone who wants to transfer ERC20 tokens have to have the required native assets in their account to pay for the gas costs.

Do note that there is no general concept of "admin" for contracts. Your contract has an admin role only if you include code which defines such admin role and gives it some special privileges.